# Redis- cache storage dividing approaches

Tags: redis

I wanted to split redis cache in different storage.We have 2 options First store in different databases(db0-db15) or second store in different instances.I have tried both but storing and manipulating data in first approach is creating problem not able to read/write data from any database other than default db0.

So I wanted to understand the pros and cons of both and why reading/writing from other then db0 is not working

Comment: use select command to change database first, then try to access keys and values from that database, https://redis.io/commands/select

Comment: Well I am giving database index while creating a connectionlike below code snippet  public List<ICacheClient> RedisClient
        {
            get
            {
                return new List<ICacheClient>() { new StackExchangeRedisCacheClient(this.connection, this.serializer) , new StackExchangeRedisCacheClient(this.connection, this.serializer, 1) };
            }
        }

Comment: It works locally but when deployed over to server it not able to get/write data from other than db0. In server We have cluster based setup 3 master and 3 slave clusters.MIght be the reason is cluster design only supports db 0.Other than that what are the casting when I am going with different clusters each cluster with db0. Please provide me link/detail for comparative study

Comment: please show code snippet (in question) with proper indentations so that it is easily readable. A badly formatted question will never get you solution